# Does photon polarization take place without scattering processes?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, scattering, polarization

Behind two perpendicular crossed polarisation filters (for visible light) the intensity of light will be zero. After installing a third filter between the two others non parallel to each of them some amount of the incoming light will go through this three filters. Therefore it's obvious that a well designed polarisation grid could rotate nearly half of the incoming photons (more exact the electric component of their EM field) and the two following filters under 45° and 90° let this light through too.
My question is, it this possible without scattering processes? Does the light has the same wavelength as before?

Comment: It would be very bad if the polarization filters changed the wavelength, given they are used with highly monochromatic laser beams.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: That the wavelength is unchanged, it is what I expected. But what is about influence from the grid on the polarization angle without scattering processes?